# Implement an OR relationship for items that can occur in a JSON schema

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, jsonschema

I am using jsonschema 4.17.3 with Python 3.7 to validate a JSON file. In this project I am facing a challenge, where I need to implement an OR relationship. This means in my case, that I require from 2 items that, either one of them is present, or both. This can be best explained with the JSON snippets below. Here, I want to be able to configure tasks for a tool. The first task is to ***download_data*** from a REST-API server and the second task is to ***upload_data*** the resulting (downloaded and converted data) to a relational database system. So, both tasks can occur together if I require my Python tool to do it all in one go.

```
{
  "tasks":{
      "download_data":{
          "targetdir": "data\\",

          "Rest":
          { 
            "type": "MyRestAPIProvider",
            "server": "MyServerName",
            "api_version": "9.99",
            "source": "production",
            "user": "de.my.corp\\User",
            "password": "!SecretPasswort!"
          }
      },
      "upload_data":{
          "zip": "",

      "database_server":{
        "host":"MyDatabaseHost",
        "port":"99999",
        "database":"MyDatabase",
        "user":"MyDatabaseUser",
        "password":"MySecretPassword"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

...but each task can also occur by itself alone (if I want to only download data, or only upload data that I have downloaded previously:

JSON sample to only download data:

```
{
  "tasks":{
      "download_data":{
          "targetdir": "data\\",

          "Rest":
          { 
            "type": "MyRestAPIProvider",
            "server": "MyServerName",
            "api_version": "9.99",
            "source": "production",
            "user": "de.my.corp\\User",
            "password": "!SecretPasswort!"
          }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

JSON sample to only upload data:

```
{
  "tasks":{
      "upload_report":{
          "zip": "",

      "database_server":{
        "host":"MyDatabaseHost",
        "port":"99999",
        "database":"MyDatabase",
        "user":"MyDatabaseUser",
        "password":"MySecretPassword"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The best JSON Schema for validating this is the JSON schema shown below. Where I actually use 3 JSON Schema files of the listing below:

1. A JSON schema containing definitions ***for both tasks*** as shown below
2. A JSON schema containing only the definitions for the ***download_data*** task (an extract from listing below)
3. A JSON schema containing only the definitions for the ***upload_data*** task (an extract from listing below)

Next, I try to validate a given JSON file against one of the 3 files and pronounce the JSON file valid, if it succeeded on 1., 2. or 3.

```
    {
      "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#",
      "type": "object",
      "properties": {
        "tasks": {
          "type": "object",
          "properties": {
            "download_data": {
              "type": "object",
              "properties": {
                "targetdir": { "type": "string" },
                "Rest": {
                  "type": "object",
                  "properties": {
                           "type": { "type": "string" },
                         "server": { "type": "string" },
                    "api_version": { "type": "string" },
                         "source": { "type": "string" },
                           "user": { "type": "string" },
                       "password": { "type": "string" }
                  }, "required": ["type", "server", "api_version", "source", "user", "password"]
                }
              },
              "required": ["targetdir", "Rest"]
            },
            "upload_data": {
              "type": "object",
              "properties": {
                "zip": { "type": "string" },
                "database_server": {
                  "type": "object",
                  "properties": {
                        "host": { "type": "string" },
                        "port": { "type": "string" },
                    "database": { "type": "string" },
                        "user": { "type": "string" },
                    "password": { "type": "string" }
                  }, "required": ["host", "port", "database", "user", "password"
                  ]
                }
              }, "required": ["zip", "database_server"]
            }
          }, "required": ["download_report", "upload_report"]
        }
      },
      "required": ["tasks"]
    }
```

My question is: What JSON schema representation do I need to validate this with only 1 JSON schema file, which should validate OK, if only one of the tasks is present, or both. But should fail, if there is no task present.

Bonus question: Is there a good recommended resource to find such non-trivial cases and learn from examples that might be available in a reference.

I have obviously been playing with this problem for a while before coming here. But so far, I have found only simple 101 style docs (https://json-schema.org/learn/getting-started-step-by-step) that do not seem to cover non-trivial cases like mine :-(

Comment: The question should be 'OR relationship' and not 'Exclusive OR' relationship. When at least one of the task or both of the tasks are present, It is OR relationship. ExclusiveOR means i should be present either of the tasks but not in both of the tasks

Comment: You are of course right - don't know why I thought its an Exclusiv Or :-(  thanks for the hint